# Passenger Configuration: Invalid command 'PassengerMinInstances'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I try to solve the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853532/slow-initial-server-startup-when-using-phusion-passenger-and-rails) by adding some [Passenger configuration options](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_configuring_phusion_passenger) to my virtual host settings, like this:

```
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.456:80>
  DocumentRoot  /var/www/my-app/public
  ServerName my-awesome-site.com
  PassengerMinInstances 1
  PassengerPoolIdleTime 1000
</VirtualHost>

PassengerPreStart http.//my-awesome-site.com
```

When I tell Apache2 to restart, it tells me:

```
Invalid command 'PassengerMinInstances', perhaps misspelled or 
defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

**My system:**
Server version: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu), Passenger version: 3.0.8

I couldn´t find an answer to this problem yet.

Any hints, folks?

Comment: Did you try moving it outside of the virtual host block? Make sure the Passenger module is loaded before this VH block.

Comment: Problem solved. I installed passenger-3.0.8 but forgot to update the Apache configuration :-( Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you complete the Passenger installation by adding the suggested code to the bottom of your Apache configuration file?

Are you running Passenger in the same version of Ruby indicated in that code at the bottom of Apache configuration?