# PassengerPreStart not really pre-starting my Rails3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I'm trying to bring down the response time of the first request server by my Rails app (deployed via Apache + Passenger). I went through the Passenger docs and [this comment on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853603/534481), and modified various Apache config files (given below). Unfortunately, the first request is still unbearably slow. What am I doing wrong?

/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger_rvm.load

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/nanda/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger_rvm.conf

```
PassengerRoot /home/nanda/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /home/nanda/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/ruby
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/beta:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName beta.myapp.com

    DocumentRoot /home/nanda/myapp/current/public
    <Directory /home/nanda/myapp/current/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/beta.error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/beta.access.log combined

    # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/853603/534481
    PassengerMinInstances 5
</VirtualHost>

PassengerPreStart http://beta.myapp.com/
PassengerPoolIdleTime 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/-_wgWV1vDj0 would answer your question?