# Auto-Load Page After Capistrano Deploy

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

I've googled but can't find an answer to my seemingly easy!? question.

After every successful Capistrano deploy the very first page load is slow, obviously due to the cache. Is it possible, as part of the deploy process as a whole, have the site automatically loaded/requested so no users ever have to experience a slow page load?

I am usually the first person to visit the site obviously, but just in case, and to also improve my 'experience' too, it would be nice

Any thoughts or ideas on this are more than welcome,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this isn't anything to do with Capistrano at all. I'm going to assume you're using Phusion Passenger to serve your app?

It's slow on the first page load because it needs to spin up a new Rails instance.

[Here is more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853603/962144).