# How can I configure rails to not use 'www' for my website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, rubber

I am not sure where this setting is.  Currently my site redirects every non-www URL to www.  I am using the Rubber gem to deploy to AWS which in turn uses Passenger, and I've seen some posts which suggest the configuration for this lies with Passenger.  I am using Apache 2

Comment: That configuration is done at the level of the Web server (nginx or Apache), not the application server (Passenger, in this case). Do you know which Web server you're using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slow initial server startup when using Phusion Passenger and Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853532/slow-initial-server-startup-when-using-phusion-passenger-and-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is done by configure correctly the virtualhost of your server (not RoR or Passenger).

You should localize the host file on your webserver (apache, nginx,..) and put something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/example1
    ServerName example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Maybe this link can help you:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: There were re-write rules.  Thank you!