# PassengerPoolIdleTime being ignored by Passenger

Tags: apache, passenger

I've followed the instructions outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853603/458960) to prevent Passenger from shutting down my app after not being used for a few minutes. However, none of this has worked.

If I refresh my website (which is just served locally on my Mac on Apache) after about 1 minute, it takes it about 6 seconds to load. After that long load, the site is now fast and everything is good. If I let it sit for another minute, refreshing again takes another 6 seconds.

Here is my `/etc/apache2/other/Passenger.conf` file:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/maq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.14/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/maq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.14
PassengerDefaultRuby /Users/maq/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby

PassengerSpawnMethod smart
PassengerPoolIdleTime 1000
RailsAppSpawnerIdleTime 0
PassengerMaxRequests 5000

PassengerMaxPoolSize 30
PassengerMinInstances 1
PassengerEnabled on
```

And I have restarted Apache after changing all these settings.

Any ideas what else it could be?

**Update:**

I tried going the cron job route, where I run a cron job every minute to access the web page and make sure it stays alive. Interestingly enough, this does not work either.

It accesses the web page properly, and I see in my logs that the page is being accessed every minute, however every time I try to access it in the browser after a minute or so of user-generated activity, there is that 6 second load up. What can this be?

Note: I am using Rails 4.0.

Comment: How does the output of `passenger-status` look like immediately after you access the site? And after 1 minute?

Comment: @Hongli they look exactly the same. Max pool size: 6, Processes: 4, Requests in top-level queue : 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the cause of my issues was not Passenger, but Apache and DNS.

It's a Mac OSX issue, and you can find out more about the problem/solution here:
http://clauswitt.com/fixing-slow-dns-queries-in-os-x-lion.html

Basically, if you have an entry in your `/etc/hosts` file called:

```
127.0.0.1 railsapp.local
```

you need to add its IPv6 counterpart so that the system doesn't go performing a remote DNS query:

```
fe80::1%lo0 railsapp.local
```