# Phusion passenger slow first load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I'm currently having problems with my ruby (1.8.7) on rails (3.2.12) apps that I have stored on a phussion passenger server, I have found that this question ([Slow initial server startup when using Phusion Passenger and Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853532/slow-initial-server-startup-when-using-phusion-passenger-and-rails)) is my problem but I don't know  where should I put the configuration that the answer says. Can somebody tell me in which file should I put the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the web server you use. If you are on Apache for example then you will find the passenger configuration here: `/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf` (See also: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#working_with_apache_conf).