# Apache initializes Rails application on first URL call only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, initializer, worker-process

There is Apache (httpd) + Phusion Passenger + Rails application bundle on server (CentOS 6.5).

I have some background threads in application which are started in an initializer.

The problem is: When `httpd` is started it does not run application and therefore background thereads aren't started too. Apache initializes application when I enter application's URL in browser's address line the first time.

When I run the same application in Webrick with `rails server` command, initializers are executed as expected.

What to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slow initial server startup when using Phusion Passenger and Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853532/slow-initial-server-startup-when-using-phusion-passenger-and-rails)

Comment: @Holger Just: I agree - there is a recipe that helped me few minutes ago.